# Data Frame in Shiny along wth search

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny. I have a dataset already in r which i want to use in shiny without read.csv function as that data is coming from google analytics and I have modified that data

Where shall i put my code for fetching data from ga and post modification code?

In UI or Server part

These are the code for data preparation

```
    query.list <- Init(start.date = "2019-10-29",
                       end.date = "2019-10-30",
                       dimensions = c("ga:dimension1","ga:dimension116"),
                       metrics = c("ga:sessions"),
                       max.results = 60000,
                       sort = "ga:sessions",
                       filters="ga:eventAction!=User Location Error",
                       table.id = "ga:xxxxxxxxx")  
    ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)

    ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, token)
    ga.data$col<-strsplit(ga.data$dimension116, "\\|")


x<-ga.data
y<- do.call(rbind, x$col)
#colnames(x) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(x)]


colnames(y)[3]<-"Plus_COde"
colnames(y)[2]<-"Long"
colnames(y)[1]<-"Lat"

df<-cbind(x[c("dimension1","sessions")], y)


#df<- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(ga.data$dimension116),'|',fixed=TRUE)))

library(revgeo)

library(ggmap)

af<-df[1:100,]

library(varhandle)
af$Lat <- unfactor(af$Lat)
af$Long <- unfactor(af$Long)


for( i in 1:nrow(af) ) {
  af$address[i] <- revgeocode(as.numeric(af[i, c("Long","Lat")]), output = "address" )
}
```

This is the output data set named dt

```
  ID Latitude Longitude      Address                             Date
1 311175 10.77294  79.13641   306/65, Parisutham Nagar           30/10/2019  
2 292058 12.97354  77.71762    EPIP Zone, Whitefield, Bengaluru  28/10/2019
3  12979 13.04037  80.19383    Sector 11, K. K. Nagar            29/10/2019
```

I want one date range which i used in ui and i want text by which i can search some data. However data is not getting loaded in shiny

ui.r

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Lat Long App"),

  fluidRow(

    column(3,
           dateRangeInput("dates", h3("Date range")))),

  fluidRow(

    column(3, 
           textInput("text", h3("Text input"), 
                     value = "Enter text..."))   
  ),
  tableOutput('dt')  
)
```

server.r

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  tableOutput('dt')
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I dont see any data loaded

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do it but initially, just stick your whole data prep in the server.r. Also, your server table is incorrect. You need a renderDataTable which has an output that is referenced in the UI.

Check out this link for more information: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderDataTable.html

Since you are new to R and building applications, it might be helpful to look up some tutorials online. Here is a good one to get you started understand how everything fits together: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/build.html

```
library(revgeo)
library(ggmap)
library(varhandle)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Lat Long App"),

  fluidRow(

    column(3,
           dateRangeInput("dates", h3("Date range")))),

  fluidRow(

    column(3, 
           textInput("text", h3("Text input"), 
                     value = "Enter text..."))   
  ),
  tableOutput('dt')  
)

server <- function(input, output) {

query.list <- Init(start.date = "2019-10-29",
                       end.date = "2019-10-30",
                       dimensions = c("ga:dimension1","ga:dimension116"),
                       metrics = c("ga:sessions"),
                       max.results = 60000,
                       sort = "ga:sessions",
                       filters="ga:eventAction!=User Location Error",
                       table.id = "ga:xxxxxxxxx")  
    ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)

    ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, token)
    ga.data$col<-strsplit(ga.data$dimension116, "\\|")


x<-ga.data
y<- do.call(rbind, x$col)
#colnames(x) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(x)]


colnames(y)[3]<-"Plus_COde"
colnames(y)[2]<-"Long"
colnames(y)[1]<-"Lat"

df<-cbind(x[c("dimension1","sessions")], y)


#df<- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(ga.data$dimension116),'|',fixed=TRUE)))

af<-df[1:100,]


af$Lat <- unfactor(af$Lat)
af$Long <- unfactor(af$Long)


for( i in 1:nrow(af) ) {
  af$address[i] <- revgeocode(as.numeric(af[i, c("Long","Lat")]), output = "address" )
}

  output$dt <- renderDataTable(af)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```